# SDL Fredhopper installation

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper

I'm looking to upgrade from SmartTarget 2011 to 2014, but have a few questions:

1. I am not able to find the web.config file for the Fredhopper website?
2. IIS is not installed in the Fredhopper server, so how is it running it?
3. How can I find the topology.txt file for the current setup?
4. Should I use the same query and index server for SmartTarget 2014?
5. Is it required to create multiple instances in Fredhopper?

Comment: Oh my, you might be a bit lost. Fredhopper doesn't run on IIS... or has anything to do with .NET.

Comment: That was my expectation too. How about my other queries?

Comment: Search the C: drive on your server, mine is in c:\Fredhopper\config\topology.txt

Comment: Index and Query are different processes, you can run them on the same server or on a separate one for production for instance. I think one instance of FH is fine, it depends if this is for production. For production you need to consider how many queries per second will be expected etc... But you can refer to your 2011 setup for some of the configuration, although make sure to check the documentation as things changed in the latest FAS, including how to start/stop instances and index/query server.

Comment: I would suggest gooing through this very basic blog of mine - I hope this may give few of the answers to your queries:
https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/sdl-fredhopper-and-smart-target/

Comment: Thanks for the easier write-up. I am still not confident on whether I should use the same query and index server from Smarttarget 2011 for Smarttarget 2014?

Comment: @Philippe - I have searched in the computer(all drives) but no topology.txt exists. I have the fredhopper located at E:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS.

Comment: You cannot use the query and index server from ST 2011, what I meant is that if in production you were running multiple instances and maybe multiple query/index servers for scalability, then you could adopt the same approach for ST 2014. However you need to upgrade the FAS to the latest for ST 2014 to run. Check the documentation for that, depending on whether you're installing ST 2014 or ST 2014 SP1. ST 2014: http://bit.ly/19f8H2x ST 2014 SP1:http://bit.ly/1B6Kjfe I would recommend using ST 2014 SP1 of course for added Experiments feature.

Comment: So the query and index servers will be installed by running the same fredhopper deployment zip package in the same server or do I need to configure them in another server and then run the package?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are all covered in the documentation (explicitly or implicitly), but I understand that might be hard to dig out. So I'll add some quick answers here:

1. There is no Web.config as Fredhopper is Java and runs its own internal web server.
2. See above. This shouldn't be relevant for you at all, by the way.
3. The topology.txt file is in Fredhopper\config.
4. Typically you would want separate index and query servers so that the query server can have 100% up-time. For non-production systems you can run them as separate instances on the same machine.
5. Yes. As mentioned in #4, you need an indexer and query instance.

If you haven't already, check out the [Quick Guide to installing SmartTarget](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D) page in the documentation. It's more visual than the rest of the documentation (lots of screenshots). Of course, there's also the [Installing and upgrading SDL SmartTarget](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-62BB9039-44CD-4EC3-8739-11097F0572D5) section of the documentation which has a lot more details but is far more text-based.

Comment: I have no  topology.txt file in my fredhopper folder E:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS. Infact I have searched in the computer(all drives) but no topology.txt exists.

Comment: In the older versions there was no topology.txt describing your setup, so you may have to create one. You can use the example from the current version, and adjust it according to your environment.